# Controlling the pop-up window of Internet Explorer instances with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to control the pop-up window once I have clicked the button on the parent window. In the pop-up window I want to be able to click the match summary button. I've looked around the internet and have not found a solution or anything that made any kind of sense for doing so.

```
Option Explicit

Sub mainproject()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument
Dim objsw As ShellWindows
Dim x As New InternetExplorer

Set objsw = New ShellWindows

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://www.flashscore.com/basketball/usa/nba/"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Loop

'Debug.Print IE.LocationName, IE.LocationURL    
IE.document.getElementById("fs-summaryfixtures ").Children(0).Children(2).Children(1).Children(2).Click ""

For Each x In objsw
    If x.LocationName = "match-summary" Then
        Set IE = x
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
Debug.Print IE.LocationName, IE.LocationURL

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm only new to this and would appreciate some feedback to what I'm doing wrong when inserting my code